# How to route traffic to k8s services using FQDN in GKE/kubedns

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kube-dns

I am trying to search for equivalent for `rewrite name` in coreDNS for kube-dns.

Am deploying a GKE cluster and kube-dns is available by default.

I need to use URL with company name even for intra-cluster traffic. For example, if the pod calls `servicename-d1.subdomain.example.com` it should  go to `servicename.d1.svc.cluster.local`. There won't be any external request to the URL

Any way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to this, [Gitlink](https://github.com/coredns/coredns/blob/master/plugin/rewrite/README.md) helps in re-writing the DNS service. This rewrite plugin offers the ability to match the name in the question section of a DNS request. The match could be exact, a substring match, or based on a prefix, suffix, or regular expression. If the newly used name is not a legal domain name, the plugin returns an error to the client.
The syntax for name rewriting is as follows:

```
rewrite [continue|stop] name [exact|prefix|suffix|substring|regex] STRING STRING [OPTIONS]
```

You can also proceed by  Kubernetes: [Routing Internal Services Through FQDN](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-routing-internal-services-through-fqdn-d98db92b79d3) refer to [link2](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)  for more information on DNS for Services and Pods.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However I was looking for a solution using kube-dns/GKE. CoreDNS for EKS is working fine. The other links you mention are using cluster service as FQDN (which works,  by my case is to use a URL to redirect to FQDN). I believe Cloud DNS is the suggested option for the same.

Comment: Cloud DNS is not permitted at my organization. We are now trying by deploying coredns with/wihtout kubedns

Comment: @ghitesh Can you have a check this  for [doc](https://blogs.infoblox.com/community/coredns-for-kubernetes-service-discovery/)  for coredns